Why doesn't RSS memory decrease when freeing memory in C++ with a thread pool?
I'm working with a C++ code snippet that utilizes a thread pool to execute multiple tasks. In each task, I create a std::vector<int> with 3 million elements. However, I'm noticing that the RSS (Resident Set Size) does not decrease after the tasks complete.
#include "BS_thread_pool.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    BS::thread_pool pool;
    pool.reset(8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        auto res = pool.submit_task([]() {
            std::vector<int> v(3000000); // Create a vector with 3 million elements
        });
        res.wait(); // Wait for task to complete
    }

    // Wait time before entering infinite loop
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    // Now enter infinite loop
    while (true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }

    return 0;
}

**Questions:
**

Why doesn't the RSS decrease after the tasks complete?
Is there a way to ensure that the memory is freed and the RSS decreases?

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions from the community. Thank you!

There are a lot of questions with answers or comments that explain why this happens. For example here or here.

Take all of the code in main and place it in a function.  If you ran a loop that calls the function, let's say 100 or even 1000 iterations, if you don't see an increase in the memory usage, then all you're observing is the heap manager doing its job.
